# Capturing variable-length groups of spaces

Tags: python, regex, whitespace, capture-group

I am trying to parse strings of the form:

```
XXX XXXX    XXXXXX   XX           XXXXXXXXXXXXX XXX
```

The objective is to capture all the variable length groups of spaces in this string.  How would I do this using regex?

Comment: what have you attempted so far?

Comment: Well `re.match(r'(( *)+)', jobs_output_li[1]).groups()` doesn't give me what I want.  I don't know regex very well.

Comment: you don't want 'match' unless you're matching from the start of the string. look into `search` and `findall`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
re.findall(r'\s+', 'XXX XXXX    XXXXXX   XX           XXXXXXXXXXXXX XXX')
```

Which gives: `[' ', '    ', '   ', '           ', ' ']`

`r'\s+'` means capture any groups of whitespace characters (1 or more). If you need strictly spaces, replace it with `r' +'`.

`re.findall` finds all non-overlapping matches in the string.